# XMPP connection issue on IOS using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xmppframework

I am trying to use the XMPP framework(https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) using swift. 
I am new to swift

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var password: NSString?
    var isOpen: Bool = false
    var xstream: XMPPStream?

    var loginServer: String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(connect())
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func connect() ->Bool{


        var xstream = XMPPStream()
        var error: NSError?
        xstream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

        xstream.myJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString("test@localhost")
        xstream.hostName="127.0.0.1"
        xstream.hostPort=5222
        var password = "testing"

        if !xstream.connectWithTimeout(XMPPStreamTimeoutNone, error: &error) {
          println(error)

        }
        println(xstream.isConnecting()) // This prints true
        return xstream.isConnected();// This prints false.
    }
}
```

The username and password and server details are correct because i use adium to connect to server and it works fine.

Comment: i am having same issue. have u got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Set your host name and port.

Call methods as described below.

- configureXMPP()
- configureXMPPElements()
- loginWithId("userId", password: "password")

After this, delegate methods will be called and authentication will be done.

After authentication, one must send presence.

`self.xmppStream.send(XMPPPresence())`

```
private var hostName: String = "your host name"
private var hostPort: UInt16 = 5222

private var xmppStream: XMPPStream!
private var xmppReconnect: XMPPReconnect!
private var xmppRoster: XMPPRoster!
private var xmppvCardStorage: XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage!
private var xmppvCardTempModule: XMPPvCardTempModule!
private var xmppvCardAvatarModule: XMPPvCardAvatarModule!

private var xmppCapabilities: XMPPCapabilities!
private var xmppCapabilitiesStorage: XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage!
private var xmppMessageArchivingStorage: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage!
private var xmppMessageArchivingModule: XMPPMessageArchiving!

private var xmppAutoPing: XMPPAutoPing!

private var userId = ""
private var password = ""

fileprivate func configureXMPP() {
    // Stream Configuration
    xmppStream = XMPPStream()
    xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppStream.hostPort = hostPort
    xmppStream.hostName = hostName
    xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = true
    xmppStream.keepAliveInterval = 0.5;
    xmppStream.startTLSPolicy = .required
}

fileprivate func configureXMPPElements() {
    //Autoping
    xmppAutoPing = XMPPAutoPing(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppAutoPing?.activate(xmppStream)
    xmppAutoPing?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    xmppAutoPing?.pingInterval = 2
    xmppAutoPing?.pingTimeout = 2

    // Reconnect
    self.xmppReconnect = XMPPReconnect()

    // Storage
    let xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage()
    self.xmppRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage, dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    self.xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = true
    self.xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true

    self.xmppvCardStorage = XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()
    self.xmppvCardTempModule = XMPPvCardTempModule(vCardStorage: xmppvCardStorage)
    self.xmppvCardAvatarModule = XMPPvCardAvatarModule(vCardTempModule: xmppvCardTempModule)

    self.xmppCapabilitiesStorage = XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()
    self.xmppCapabilities = XMPPCapabilities(capabilitiesStorage: xmppCapabilitiesStorage)

    self.xmppMessageArchivingStorage = XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()
    self.xmppMessageArchivingModule = XMPPMessageArchiving(messageArchivingStorage: xmppMessageArchivingStorage)
    self.xmppMessageArchivingModule.clientSideMessageArchivingOnly = false

    self.xmppMessageArchivingModule.activate(self.xmppStream)
    self.xmppMessageArchivingModule.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

    //Activate xmpp modules
    self.xmppReconnect.activate(self.xmppStream)
    self.xmppRoster.activate(self.xmppStream)
    self.xmppvCardTempModule.activate(self.xmppStream)
    self.xmppvCardAvatarModule.activate(self.xmppStream)
    self.xmppCapabilities.activate(self.xmppStream)

    // Add ourself as a delegate to anything we may be interested in
    self.xmppRoster.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
}

func loginWithId(_ userId: String, password: String) {
    if self.xmppStream == nil {
        establishConnection()
    }
    self.userId = userId
    self.password = password
    xmppStream.myJID = XMPPJID(string: userId)

    do {
        try xmppStream?.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
    } catch {
        print("connection failed")
    }
}

fileprivate func authentictae() {
    do {
        try self.xmppStream.authenticate(withPassword: password)
    }
    catch {
        print("not authenticate")
    }
}

// Delegate Methods
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream!, socketDidConnect socket: GCDAsyncSocket!) {
    print("socketDidConnect:")
    sender.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = true
}

func xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
    print("xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation:")
}

func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
    authentictae()
    print("Stream: Connected")
}

func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream!) {
    print("Stream: Authenticated")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the connection takes some seconds to be established. 
Use the other delegate methods to track the state of the connection.