# How to connect xmpp-messenger-iOS with openfire server in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, openfire, xmppframework

I have just started to work on chat application in iOS and I have integrated xmpp-messenger-ios library in my project. Now i want to connect to openfire server? I have tried Github source code but its complex here is the link https://github.com/processone/xmpp-messenger-ios
Please help?

Comment: Have you studied XMPP protocol? Also do you have installed Openfire server available (locally or on some of your server)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes i studied XMPP protocol and I do have a server. I tried code from stackoverflow. But I get the same error.
     `xstream.isConnected() `  returns true
     `xstream.isConnected()`   returns false
here is the link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154422/xmpp-connection-issue-on-ios-using-swift]

Comment: Have you first tried connecting to server using a desktop IM client like Spark? If Spark is successfully connecting, then it will be confirmed that issue is on mobile side.

Comment: No I did not. And what is spark? Please don't mind I am a beginner?

Comment: Spark is a desktop instant messaging client, so you can connect to XMPP server (Openfire). As a beginner, you should first start using it. here is the link: https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/ and we can't discuss much details here in comments. So please post specific issues.